# Using Docker Container as a REST API

Tags: rest, api, docker, containers

I was working on a software using Docker wherein I have my container uploaded on Docker. Is there any way that I could convert the container into a REST API and simply make calls to it in my software ?

Comment: Running REST services inside Docker containers is extremely normal; is there a specific problem you're having?

Answer (score 5):

A little remark first: You don't upload containers, you upload *images*.

Further than that, of course you can run an API inside a container. In order to call it from another application, you would have to configure the container's network properly.

[Here](https://github.com/bellackn/airport_data) you can find a small example of a Python Flask API running inside a Docker container, which I built as a coding challenge. It's far from perfect, but you should get the idea from that.